# Dynamic LIKE in Where Clause statement

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I've been trying my best to achieve dynamic query for the LIKE statement

From the below SQL query instead of doing ilike for every value and it may grow in large. I cannot rewrite the query again and again for new table_name value .. I can store those values in a separate table, But How do I achieve it dynamically

```
  SELECT
        t.table_name as table_name,
        t.table_schema as table_schema
    FROM
       information_schema.tables T
    WHERE  (table_schema  ilike 'stage' and table_name  like 'ABC%') or (table_schema  ilike 'stage' and table_name  like 'EFG%');
```

I can have another table with a list of values like below

create or replace table  tempdw.blk_table;
   (
     db_name varchar,
     tbl_expr varchar
   );

insert into  tempdw.blk_table  values ('stage','ABC%');
   insert into  tempdw.blk_table  values ('stage','EFG%');

select * from tempdw.blk_table;

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a table with tables and schemas in them, you could always collate your join to take care of the case-sensitive part:

```
SELECT
    t.table_name as table_name,
    t.table_schema as table_schema
FROM
   information_schema.tables T
JOIN
   table_names tn
ON collate(t.table_name , 'en-ci') like collate(tn.table_name , 'en-ci')
AND collate(t.table_schema, 'en-ci') = collate(tn.schema_name, 'en-ci');
```

Comment: I have updated the original question , the other table has list of like values

Comment: Can still do that.  Updated my answer to reflect assuming that only the table name is a like.

Comment: What is 'en-ci'

Comment: It can be seen that is a parameter to the collate function, thus Googling `snowflake collate` take you to https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/collate.html where it explains its a collation specification https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/collation.html#label-collation-specification which is a fancy way of telling string library how to translate complex non-English tokens as they are can or cannot be considered the equal.

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking for a set of tables with prefixes, you could use `regexp_like()`:

```
where table_schema ilike 'stage' and
      regexp(lower(table_name), '^abc|efg')
```

Comment: I don't want to hard the values here ..I have updated the original question, which I have another table which stores all the values